# how to print square matrix w/o numpy?

Tags: python, string, matrix

I'm trying to write a python 3 code that prints out square matrix from user input. In addition the first row of this matrix must be filled by numbers from 1,n, the second row is the multiplication of the first row by 2, the third by 3, etc., until n-th row, which is created by the first row being multiplied by n.  I was able to get my code to print out the square matrix but I do not understand how can I modified it so that it prints according to the earlier description. So, for example for n=3 I should have matrix : 1 2 3 (1st row), 2 4 6 (2nd row) and
3 6 9 (3rd row) but instead I get 1 2 3 (1st row), 4 5 6 (2nd row) and 7 8 9 (3rd row).

My code:

```
n = int(input("Enter dimensions of matrix :"))
m = n
x = 1
columns = []
for row in range(n):
    inner_column = []
    for col in range(m):
        inner_column.append(x)
        x = x + 1
    columns.append(inner_column)
for inner_column in columns:
    print(' '.join(map(str, inner_column)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just complementing @mix_42's answer. One shouldn't use `enumerate(range(n))`, since `enumerate` returns a tuple for each element in its argument. So for n=3, if you do `list(enumerate(range(n)))`, you'll have `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]` as output. If all indices are equal to their corresponding elements, why use `enumerate`? You'd better do instead

```
matrix=[]
for i in range(1, n+1):
  matrix.append([col*i for col in range(1, n+1)])
```

To print the matrix:

```
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for col in matrix[i]:
        print(col,end='\t')
    print('\n')
```

You can do `print(i, row)` in the outer loop to understand better how enumerate works.

Comment: @Cario Rocha this works in the way I need it to work. Just need to figure out how to change the print formatting to remove extra space between  rows. Thank you!

Comment: with the last print being print() it works perfectly for me.

Comment: @nina you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer that goes best with your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

you may use:

```
n = int(input("Enter dimensions of matrix :"))
m = n
columns = []
for row in range(1, n +1):
    inner_column = []
    for  col in range(row, n*row + 1, row):
        inner_column.append(col)
    columns.append(inner_column)
for inner_column in columns:
    print(''.join([e.ljust(4) for e in map(str, inner_column)]))
# input 4
```

output:

```
1   2   3   4   
2   4   6   8   
3   6   9   12  
4   8   12  16
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @kederrac. I don't quite get how the enumerate works, beside in my case for n=4 the output should be: in the first row a11 = 1, a12 = 2, a13 = 3, a14 = 4; second row a21 = 2, a22 = 4, a23 = 6, a24=8, third row  a31 = 3, a32 = 6, a33 = 9, a34 = 12 and the fourth  a41 = 4, a42 = 8, a43 = 12, a44 = 16.

Comment: @nina check now my answer

Comment: that works. Thank you. Now I know two ways got to achieve this.

Comment: @nina if one of the answers solves your issue you may accept that answer

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand, you're issue is with the contents of the matrix itself.

In that case, python has an `enumerate` function which can be looped through as such:

```py
ls = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
for n, i in enumerate(ls):
  print(n, i)
```

Which would give the following output:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Essentially, each iteration over an enumerated object gives a tuple with the index of the iteration and the element itself (I am saying this of the top of my head, I am not sure if it is a tuple or not. I encourage looking further into this on google as there are many great examples).

So, in your case, you could fill up the matrix by multiplying the index of the iteration with the actual value itself. This is how I would do it:

```py
for it, n in enumerate(range(n)):
  arr = []
  for col in range(n): # since its a square matrix, you can reuse n
    arr.append((col+1)*(it+1))
  matrix.append(arr)
```

Even better, you can use a generator, but this might be a bit confusing.

```py
for it, num in enumerate(range(n)):
  matrix.append([(col+1)*(it+1) for col in range(n)])
```

I hope you understood, and please do comment if there are any stupid mistakes in my answer.

Comment: my output when I use your suggestion @mix_42: "Enter dimensions of matrix M :3
[] [1] [2, 4]"

Comment: `columns = []
for i, row in enumerate(range(1,n+1)):
    inner_column = []
    for col in range(m):
        inner_column.append(col+1 * i)
#        x = x + 1
    columns.append(inner_column)
for inner_column in columns:
    print(' '.join(map(str, inner_column)))`

Comment: gives me:  "Enter dimensions of matrix M :3" \\newline
0 1 2 \\(1st row)
1 2 3 \\(2nd row)
2 3 4 \\ (3rd row)

Comment: so basically what I want except it starts form 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @nina good catch. I forgot that enumerate starts with index 0. So 1 should be to the index before its multiplied with the column value. It should work now. I fixed it in the answer, thanks!

Comment: @nina I understand that the loop I have included in my answer does not work properly for some reason. The generator works, though, have you tried using that?

Comment: I just tried it using"generator" and it works, just the printing formatting is not exactly what I need. Thank you again for your help.